# $\kappa$ $\lambda$-supercompact $\longrightarrow\lambda$ is represented by the "order type" function in the ultrapower

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, large-cardinals

If $\kappa$ is a $\lambda$-supercompact cardinal, then there exists a normal fine measure on $P_\kappa(\lambda)$. In Jech, Set Theory, we read that a function representing the ordinal $\lambda$ of the ultrapower is $f:P\mapsto ot(P)$ (order type).

He suggests to use the following: if $j$ is the elementary embedding of $V$ in the ultrapower and $G=\{j(\gamma):\gamma<\lambda\}$, then $[f]=jf(G)$ if $f$ is a function $f:P_\kappa(\lambda)\longrightarrow V$.

I am stuck in finding how to use these two facts. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Where* does Jech suggest this? Which version of Set Theory? (And might I suggest Kanamori for large cardinals related stuff?)

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be a normal, fine measure on $\mathcal{P}_{\kappa}(\lambda)$, let $M := \mathrm{Ult}(V; U)$ be the ultrapower of $V$ by $U$ (which we identify with its transitive collapse) and let
$$
j \colon V \to M, x \mapsto [c_x]
$$
be the canonical elementary embedding.

*Step 1.* Let $d \colon \mathcal P_{\kappa}(\lambda) \to \mathcal P_{\kappa})(\lambda), X \mapsto X$ be the identity function. By Lemma 20.13 we have that $$[d] = j"\lambda := \{ j(\gamma) \mid \gamma \in \lambda \} = G.$$

*Step 2.* Note that
$$
\begin{align*}
(jf)(j"\lambda) &= [c_f](j"\lambda) \\
&= [c_f]([d]).
\end{align*}
$$
Now, by Łoś' Theorem,
$$
\begin{align*}
[f] = (jf)(j" \lambda) & \iff [f] = [c_f]([d]) \\
& \iff \{ X \in \mathcal P_{\kappa}(\lambda) \mid f(X) = c_f(X)(d(X)) \} \in U
\end{align*}
$$
But $\{ X \in \mathcal P_{\kappa}(\lambda) \mid f(X) = c_f(X)(d(X)) \} = \mathcal P_{\kappa}(\lambda)$ is certainly in $U$. Q.E.D.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Hint: Use this, the elementarity of $j$ and the fact that all transitive models of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ compute the order types of their sets correctly to conclude that $[f] = \lambda$, where $f$ is as in your post.

Comment: Thank you. So the order type of $G$ is $\lambda$; but is the same true for $(jf)(G)$? And do I know that $[f]$ is an ordinal?

Comment: To see that $[f]$ is an ordinal, use Los. But you seem to be on the wrong track. Here is an additional hint: $f \colon \mathcal P_{\kappa}(\lambda) \to V, X \mapsto \mathrm{ot}(X)$. What kind of function is $j(f)$ (use elementarity and absoluteness)? Once you answered that: What is $j(f)(G)$?